# AWS Redshift as source for DMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-dms

Can I use AWS Redshift as source for AWS DMS?

When I am trying to connect it to as MySql source endpoint in DMS, it is giving error in testing connection:

**Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Cannot connect to ODBC provider  ODBC general error., Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: HY000 NativeError: 2003 Message: [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on '.redshift.amazonaws.com' (110)**

Any workaround to treat Redshift as source endpoint for DMS?

Comment: Amazon Redshift is not listed as a [Source for data migration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.html) in the AWS Database Migration Service. You _might_ be able to pretend that it is a PostgreSQL database, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: Ok will check as Postgres

Comment: @SushilVerma what did you find out?

Comment: @SushilVerma I am interested to know too

Comment: I used AWS Glue as DMS does not support Redshift as source till now

Comment: Have you tried using Postgres as a type for your Redshift source?

Comment: No. I used Glue

Comment: I am interested to hear if selecting Postgres as a type helped for Redshift Source in DMS ?

Comment: I tried the `postgres` method for the sake of it to see what would happen :
`Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failure in resolving database version.  ODBC general error., Application-Detailed-Message: Failed retrieve database backend version RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: XX000 NativeError: 1 Message: ERROR: Fetch size 10000 exceeds the limit of 1000 for a single node configuration. Reduce the client fetch/cache size or upgrade to a multi node installation.; Error while executing the query Failed (retcode -1) to execute statement`

Comment: no, you cannot use the `postgres` legacy that Redshift carries with it for AWS DMS.
Fortunately, I had most of the data in Redshift in other means of databases that was supported by DMS. I did not want to get involved with the complexities of writing AWS Glue scripts to migrate the data. It was additional effort in migrating multiple database sources, but that was what was my approach to this problem.